# Struts2 Multiple File Upload with Map

Tags: file-upload, struts2, dynamic

I am doing Multiple file upload with Struts2. It was working fine I map with java static action properties. But I am using Map to collect all the files. I am getting only the file object. I am not getting the fileName and content type.

```
public class TableListAction extends ActionSupport 
{
    private Map raja;
    public Map getRaja() 
     {
    return raja;
     }
    public void setRaja(Map raja) 
     {
    this.raja = raja;
     }
     public String upload() throws Exception 
     {
        System.out.println(raja);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

My Jsp like this

```
<s:form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload">
<s:file name="raja['column']"></s:file>
<s:file name="raja['column']"></s:file>
<s:file name="raja['column']"></s:file>
<s:file name="raja['column']"></s:file>
<s:submit/>
```

During uploading I am getting the file object array in that `raja` Map but I am not getting the fileName and contenttype.

Thanks in Advance

regards
Shreeram A

Comment: Try creating maps for the other two fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<s:form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload">
<s:file name="raja.column"></s:file>
<s:file name="raja.column"></s:file>
<s:file name="raja.column"></s:file>
<s:file name="raja.column"></s:file>
<s:submit/>
```

They are append name attribute with FileName and ContentType.

I used before name like this **raja['column']**, so the result **raja['column']FileName** and 
**raja['column']ContentType**. It wont come into the the Map.

Then i modified  **raja.column**. Then it will append FileName and ContentType correctly like **raja.columnContentType** and  **raja.columnFileName**

Its work fine now.
Thanks
**Shreeram A**